# libgit2sharp solve file conflict using theirs

Tags: libgit2sharp

I use the libgit2sharp library and I have a question:
how to solve file conflict "using theirs"?

I need to do that only for one file.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the conflict resolve strategy Theirs:

```
MergeOptions opts = new MergeOptions() { FileConflictStrategy = CheckoutFileConflictStrategy.Theirs };
repo.Merge(branch, this._signature, opts);
```

Comment: This will perform a merge and take the theirs side for conflicts in any file.  I think that the OP has already performed a merge and wants to simply take the complete "theirs" file in a conflict that already exists.

Comment: Well, you are not alone in such question. So, I have no idea as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812895/libgit2sharp-how-to-resolve-a-conflict