# LibGit2Sharp how to resolve a conflict?

Tags: c#, .net, libgit2sharp

Using libgit2sharp I am merging changes from two users:

```
public void Merge(string branchName)
{
    using (Repository repo = new Repository(this._settings.Directory))
    {
        var branch = repo.Branches[branchName];
        MergeOptions opts = new MergeOptions() { FileConflictStrategy = CheckoutFileConflictStrategy.Merge };
        repo.Merge(branch, this._signature, opts);

        if (repo.Index.Conflicts.Count() > 0)
        {
             //TODO: resolve conflicts
        } 
    }
}
```

Even if the strategy is set to merge the conflics still appear. I found no way to resolve the conflict. The Conflict object have no Resolve method.

Is there a way to resolve a conflict from code apart from removing file or renaming it? Is there any auto resolve functionality?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: A merge conflict either has to be resolved manually or you would need to overwrite the file with either a `theirs` or `our` style merge checkout. This is the same that you would have to do via the CLI with `git merge xxxx`

Comment: @RobertN Thank you for the replay. Is this mean that I have to find a file for conflict, read the entier content of the file, somehow find the conflicted part, replace it with theirs or our, write the content to the disk and than call Merge again?

Comment: Someone else wrote an answer, but in regards to your comment, once you correct/fix the file(s) in conflict, you would than stage and commit them as your local repo is still in a state of 'merging'

Comment: @RobertN Ok, I will try. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LibGit2Sharp *does* do an automerge.  If you are seeing conflicts, then the files are unmergeable.  An example of an unmergeable conflict is when both branches change the same region of the same file.

In this case, LibGit2Sharp will write the file to the working directory, with markup around the conflicting region.  For example, if some file `foo.txt` has a conflict, it may look like:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
this is a change in HEAD
=======
this is a change in the other branch
>>>>>>> other branch
```

To resolve the conflict, place the content that you want to accept in the working directory, then stage it using `Repository.Index.Add("foo.txt")`.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I will try to show the conflicting parts to the user. Now it is clear how to resolve the conflict. Thank you!